# Error about Invalid or unexpected token in javascript and jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a span tag with two classes, `action` and `delete`

```
<span class="action delete"> delete</span>
```

and I use jQuery to select this span:

```
var $delete_task ＝ $('.action.delete')
```

after running, there will be an error of
`Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token`
Please tell me how to solve.

Comment: What was the unexpected token or the full error?

Comment: it shows that  $('.action.delete') is a Invalid or unexpected token

Comment: try single class selector `$('.action)` or `$('.delete')`

Comment: try `var $delete_task ＝ $('.action delete')`

Comment: @ruibohe  : can you reproduce the problem in stacksnippet or http://jsfiddle.net

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out that the culprit is your `＝` character. This is not a standard `=` sign. (Notice the first one is a little longer)

Here is what happens with the invalid `＝`: (Error is expected!)

```js
var $delete_task ＝ $('.action.delete');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span class="action delete"> delete</span>
```

**And here it is with the updated `=`:**

```js
var $delete_task = $('.action.delete');
console.log($delete_task[0]);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span class="action delete"> delete</span>
```

Comment: it really helpful, I found the typo in '=', That's difficult to find out.

Comment: @KevBot nice observation

Answer (score 0):

```js
  var $deletetask = $(".action.delete").text();
  console.log($deletetask);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span class="action delete"> delete</span>
```